# Где должен быть файл, который я хочу прочитать с freopen в c++

Tags: c++

Где должен быть файл, который я хочу прочитать с freopen в c++

Comment: Каких-то специальных ограничений на расположение нет. Напишите подробнее, что не получается.

Comment: у мена фаил которий я хочу написать с freopen в c++ в C  диск но нечего  не получается

Answer (score 1):

```
freopen("Путь до файла, "режим чтения", "Указатель на объект типа FILE, который соединен с потоком");
```

Если напишешь к примеру:

```
freopen("file.txt", "w", stdout);
```

Путь до файла в директории, где запускается приложение, то есть где запускается exe файл, но путь можешь прописать любой.

Comment: Не в директории, где запускается приложение, а в _текущей_ директории. Это немного разные вещи.

Comment: Да и ещё текущая директория для каждого диска своя..

Comment: Но где запускается приложение от этого пути идет отчет. И в текущей дериктории относительно чего?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете в кач-ве параметра передать, так называемый абсолютный путь к файлу, например

```
 freopen("C:\\t.txt", "r", stdin)

 // В случае ниже файл должен быть в папке с исполняемым файлом
 freopen("t.txt", "r", stdin)
```

Comment: Только не с исходниками, а с исполняемым файлом. А еще точнее - в *current directory*.

Comment: @Ternvein да, спасибо)